# Can we have axis2 folder under some another folder instead of directly placing it under webapps.?

Tags: tomcat, soapui, apache-axis, soap-client

I want my URL to be like: http://myhost/phase5/axis2/services/ instead of http://myhost/axis2/services/.

So to achieve this i need to place axis2 folder under phase5 folder .

Like my folder structure will be ->Tomcat/webapps/phase5/axis2/. but after doing this when i hit SOAP req i am getting resource not found error.

Is this possible to keep axis2 folder under some another folder ? Kindly suggest .

Comment: How is this related to the tool [tag:soapui]?

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. So posting that it might help someone. It is not possible as Tomcat structure is like this only. So for my problem i rename the folder axis2 with axis2-phase5.